# Erro ao Instalar lib react-navigation-tabs e react-navigation-drawler

Tags: react-native

Depois que eu instalo as dependências e importo para o projeto ele da esse erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo executa esse dois comandos:

```
yarn add react-navigation-tabs
react-native link react-navigation-tabs
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo

Comment: funcionou amigo, muito obrigado!